# Wrapper over template classes c++/cli

Tags: c++-cli

I am trying to create a c++ cli/clr wrapper over a project based on .hpp files (that does not generate .dll or .lib). My problem is as follows:

Let's say I have:

```
class A
{
    A();
    void DoAStuff();
}

class B
{
    B();
    void DoBStuff();
}

class C
{
    C();
    void DoCStuff();
}

template <typename AorB>
class AB
{
    AB();
    AorB GetAB();
}

template <typename CType>
class CClass
{
    CClass();
    CType GetCClass();
}
```

And inside the wrapper project I have 2 enums and a class with a method:

```
public enum class AorBEnum
{
    A = 0,
    B = 1
};

public enum class CEnum
{
    C = 0
};

void UseCode(TypeForAB ab, TypeForC c)
{
    unknowntype a;
    unknowntype b;

    switch(ab)
    {
    case AorBEnum::A_TYPE:
        a = AB<A>();
    case AorBEnum::B_TYPE:
        a = AB<B>();
    }

    switch(c)
    {
    case CEnum::C_TYPE:
        b = CClass(C);
    }

    unknowntype vala = a.GetAB();
    unknowntype valb = b.GetCClass();
}
```

What I am trying to do is create some objects using the parameters given to UseCode, then use methods from those objects.

Imagine I have a lot more classes and enums like these.

**The question is: What can I use instead of unknowntype for it to work?**

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: the question is: What can I use instead of unknowntype for it to work?

Comment: Have you looked into [.NET generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssea4yk6.aspx) to get somewhere?